# How to determine if a click event was caused by submitting a form with "enter"?

Tags: javascript, html

When you submit a form by pressing "enter" where the form also has an input with type="submit", it triggers a "click" event on the submit button. I have a global click event listener, is it possible to determine if the click event came from an actual click or from submitting a form using "enter"?

Comment: This is easily accomplishable, however, there is also a lot of "it depends" involved with how to solve some scenarios. A blanket "watch the keyboard event" answer works to some degree, which looks like it was posted, but giving an actual example here would really help you get a better solution.

Comment: What kind of example would help? I just have `window.addEventListener('click', doSomething)`, but submitting forms via "enter" also triggers this, which I don't want

Comment: This is the result of the browser issuing a false click event. Recently there was a bug in chrome related to this as well (https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/8616084?hl=en). Chrome also issues false events during user scroll on touch devices, as a related instance of event problems in modern browsers. Using type="submit" on an input element should be avoided due to inconsistencies with platform adoption if there is to be widespread browser support. Any hacks will end up producing unintended behavior during browser updates.

Comment: @TravisJ the synthetic click event on the submit button or input is per specs, it always has been. The bug you linked to was that they did submit the form again from this synthetic click.

Comment: @Kaiido - Mandating a click isn't listed in the w3. Instead, the spec specifically indicates that the input element itself should originate the submission event by calling the form owner. Reaching out to try to find the first available submission button to click on is a hack. The spec relates to submit buttons being "An enumerated value, with the extra semantic that it must be the last value selected and initiates form submission" and " if the element has a form owner, and the element’s node document is fully active, submit the form owner from the input element".

Comment: Bypassing the hack is easily done, by introducing a faux element there and then cancelling anything attached to it, but that will only work until there is a browser update to address the already shoddy implementation.

Comment: @TravisJ https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#implicit-submission "If the user agent supports letting the user submit a form implicitly (for example, on some platforms hitting the "enter" key while a text control is focused implicitly submits the form), then doing so for a form, whose default button has activation behavior and is not disabled, **must cause the user agent to fire a click event** at that default button."

Comment: Interesting that it states that, since it is not entirely accurate. It is a version of interpretation that the editor of that segment chose to use, but it is not necessarily the spec that W3C defines. Clearly on the implementation side, browser authors chose to cut corners, and this is a representation of that. I do appreciate the source though, almost a situation of the tail wagging the dog if implementation is to come from a reflection of the current state of the feature rather than the design of the feature.

Comment: W3C has no authority over HTML specs and all UAs do the same thing: they fire a click event on the default submit button, just as asked by the specs.

Comment: @Kaiido - Ah, wow, I hadn't realized that the W3C ceded the authority of the spec to WHATWG. That is quite a change, thank you for the additional information, I will definitely need to update the source I cite going forward and appreciate the correction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keyboard events` to identify whether `ENTER` is pressed or not. Just assign a class name to all your input fields & select in your `javascript`. Here's a quick snippet:

```js
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('form');
elements.forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      // Do Stuff
    }
  });
})
```

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: How do you know the `keydown` event listener callback will fire (to do its job) before the other `submit` event callbacks?

Comment: It's possible that users pressed "enter" without submitting the form, then they click somewhere. The click handler won't be able to tell the difference

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the `offsetX` and `offsetY` properties of the event, which would be `0` on a synthetic click event, if you don't have to support IE you can also check the [`.detail` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/detail), which would be `0` on a synthetic click event.
However note that these won't help you differentiate from a synthetic `.click()` call.

```js
onsubmit = (evt) => evt.preventDefault();
onclick = (evt) => {
  console.log( "detail", evt.detail );
  console.log( "offsetX", evt.offsetX );
  console.log( "offsetY", evt.offsetY );
};
```

```html
<form>
  <input>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Looks like this is the best option at the moment, I'm also checking target type: `if (e.clientX === 0 && e.clientY === 0 && e.screenX === 0 && e.screenY === 0 && (e.target as any).type === 'submit')`

Comment: ..  unfortunately clientX and clientY will be set on Safari relatively to the button.  The best is to only check for detail, which would fail only on IE.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a global click event listener, is it possible to determine if the click event came from an actual click or from submitting a form using "enter"?

As the specification requires a click for enter in this scenario, a ghost submit will suffice. This will both create a hook to use in order to take action, if the submission is still logically valid, and as well create a flag to use in case the event needs to be handled. See the spec below:

> **[4.10.21.2 Implicit submission](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#implicit-submission)**
> A form element's default button is the first submit button in tree order whose form owner is that form element.
> If the user agent supports letting the user submit a form implicitly (for example, on some platforms hitting the "enter" key while a text control is focused implicitly submits the form), then doing so for a form, whose default button has activation behavior and is not disabled, must cause the user agent to fire a click event at that default button.

```js
window.addEventListener('click', doSomething);

function doSomething(e){
 if(e.target.id === 'implicitSubmit'){
  // Todo: Handle implicit submit

  console.log('browser click detected');
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
 }
 console.log('organic click');
}

document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = _ => !1;
```

```html
<form>
<input type="submit" id="implicitSubmit" style="display:none;" />
<input />
<input type="submit" value="Test" />
<form>
```

If the pattern is more involved, for example there are more forms, or there is less control over the structure of inputs, there are other ways to accomplish this as well.

Comment: Fails if you press enter on the submit button directly (after setting focus)

Comment: @Kaiido - Directly focusing any button and pressing enter I believe does count as a click. Space bar will work as well in that scenario

Comment: The spec (ty) does also state that, "When the user triggers an element with a defined activation behavior in a manner other than clicking it, the default action of the interaction event must be to fire a click event at the element." -https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#activation

Comment: indeed it does. I don't see anything in OP stating we can ignore this case. Also your code prevents the default submission of the form through this enter key.

Comment: This code does prevent the default submission, however, removing the false return or removing the preventDefault will allow it there. I was unsure what the desired outcome was, and for the sake of showing the situation was being monitored in the event handler, I prevented the default from taking place here.

Comment: The click event is legitimate though in the case you raise, as that is the recommended action to react to, when a button element is focused and then enter is pressed (or space bar).

Answer (score -1):

You can use a hidden field into your form and check its value.